# clickMapObject method in amCharts V4 maps

Tags: amcharts

I need a hand to find a way to to replicate the following functionality from amcharts v3 in v4 without success:

In V3:  map.clickMapObject(map.getObjectById('CA'));
In V4: chart.METHOD???(polygonSeries.getPolygonById("CA"))

What I'm looking to achieve here is to open the area modal from a click on an element outside the map.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v4 you would assign a `hit` event ([our Events guide](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/event-listeners/)) on the `polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template`, e.g.:

```js
// Open modal on click
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(event) {
  // chart.closeAllPopups(); // <-- if using an amCharts Popup
  chart.openModal(
    "The id for " +
      event.target.dataItem.dataContext.name +
      " is <strong>" +
      event.target.dataItem.dataContext.id +
      "</strong>."
  );
  // if using an amCharts popup, replace openModal with openPopup
});
```

Wasn't sure what was meant by area modal, so I showed how to use amCharts' Modal in the code and in comments is a way to use amCharts' Popups. Here's our guide on Popups and Modals: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/popups-and-modals/

To trigger an event you coulde use the object's `dispatch` or `dispatchImmediately` methods. So you were spot on with `polygonSeries.getPolygonById("CA")`. It would look something like `polygonSeries.getPolygonById("CA").dispatchImmediately("hit")`, e.g.:

```js
// External button that interacts with map, triggers click event of a MapPolygon
var $button = document.getElementById("external-interaction");
chart.events.on("inited", function(event) {
  $button.style.display = "inline-block";
  $button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    polygonSeries.getPolygonById("CA").dispatchImmediately("hit");
  });
});
```

Here's a demo with all that thrown together:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/9b6d270e43c4a6d32a955fd7ac9a65c9?editors=0011

Let us know if this is making sense and is along the lines of what you were looking to do.

Comment: excelent, dispatchImmediately("hit"); was the method I was looking for.